# Swift 3 - Retrieving a specific part of a String

Tags: swift, string

I'm relatively new to Swift3 and I can't make heads or tails of how to implement the following:

I have a String that looks like this:

`"45007KÖPENHAMN H45012KÖPENHAMN NØRREPORT45011KÖPENHAMN ØSTERPORT45006CPH AIRPORT91220SIMRISHAMN BISKOP ESKILSGATAN439872KÖPENHAMNSKAJEN 1 HELSINGBORG217696KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 1 MALMÖ217741KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 2 MALMÖ217774KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 3A MALMÖ217775KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 3B MALMÖ222954ARKEN, KÖPENHAMN192513COPENHAGEN MALMÖ PORT (CMP) MALMÖ192654ARILDS GÄSTHAMN HÖGANÄS192657DOMSTENS GÄSTHAMN HELSINGBORG181286FRISKVÅRDSENHET LIMHAMN95006GÖTEBORG C87071TRELLEBORG C80520MALMÖ LINDEBORG CENTRUM33437VYSTEBORGSVÄGEN 27 BÅSTAD435959SKARHULT SKATTEBORG FLYINGE238027LINDEBORGSGATAN 1 MALMÖ306369LILJEBORGSGATAN 1 TRELLEBORG235750SÖVDEBORGSGATAN 3 MALMÖ37006BIBLIOTEK TRELLEBORG193244BÖSTE BED & BREAKFAST TRELLEBORG193083HOTELL & PENSIONAT MAGLARP TRELLEBORG67151HOTELL HORIZONT TRELLEBORG48053KATTEBÄCKSSKOLAN TRELLEBORG"`

The format is 5(or 6)-digit-code, then the name of the place the code belongs to.

What I need to do is locate a specific name, say "FRISKVÅRDSENHET LIMHAMN" and retrieve the code in front of it (in this case 181286)

I have searched extensively but all the examples of String searching/indexing I have found involve moving a set distance from the start/end of the String, which isn't helpful in my case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy with regular expression.

You have to search for *5-6 digits followed by the query string*.

```
"(\\d{5,6})" + query
```

The pair of parentheses around the regex pattern captures the number which is available later in the match at range index 1.

```
let string = "45007KÖPENHAMN H45012KÖPENHAMN NØRREPORT45011KÖPENHAMN ØSTERPORT45006CPH AIRPORT91220SIMRISHAMN BISKOP ESKILSGATAN439872KÖPENHAMNSKAJEN 1 HELSINGBORG217696KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 1 MALMÖ217741KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 2 MALMÖ217774KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 3A MALMÖ217775KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 3B MALMÖ222954ARKEN, KÖPENHAMN192513COPENHAGEN MALMÖ PORT (CMP) MALMÖ192654ARILDS GÄSTHAMN HÖGANÄS192657DOMSTENS GÄSTHAMN HELSINGBORG181286FRISKVÅRDSENHET LIMHAMN95006GÖTEBORG C87071TRELLEBORG C80520MALMÖ LINDEBORG CENTRUM33437VYSTEBORGSVÄGEN 27 BÅSTAD435959SKARHULT SKATTEBORG FLYINGE238027LINDEBORGSGATAN 1 MALMÖ306369LILJEBORGSGATAN 1 TRELLEBORG235750SÖVDEBORGSGATAN 3 MALMÖ37006BIBLIOTEK TRELLEBORG193244BÖSTE BED & BREAKFAST TRELLEBORG193083HOTELL & PENSIONAT MAGLARP TRELLEBORG67151HOTELL HORIZONT TRELLEBORG48053KATTEBÄCKSSKOLAN TRELLEBORG"

let query = "FRISKVÅRDSENHET LIMHAMN"

let pattern = "(\\d{5,6})" + query

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
    if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count)) {
        let range = match.rangeAt(1)
        let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
        let end = string.index(start, offsetBy: range.length)
        print(string.substring(with: start..<end))
    } else {
        print("\(query) not found")
    }
} catch {
    print("Regex Error:", error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58f5ebe15d728d386669ab90

```
//  Write some awesome Swift code, or import libraries like "Foundation",
//  "Dispatch", or "Glibc"
import Foundation

let input = "45007KÖPENHAMN H45012KÖPENHAMN NØRREPORT45011KÖPENHAMN ØSTERPORT45006CPH AIRPORT91220SIMRISHAMN BISKOP ESKILSGATAN439872KÖPENHAMNSKAJEN 1 HELSINGBORG217696KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 1 MALMÖ217741KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 2 MALMÖ217774KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 3A MALMÖ217775KÖPENHAMNSVÄGEN 3B MALMÖ222954ARKEN, KÖPENHAMN192513COPENHAGEN MALMÖ PORT (CMP) MALMÖ192654ARILDS GÄSTHAMN HÖGANÄS192657DOMSTENS GÄSTHAMN HELSINGBORG181286FRISKVÅRDSENHET LIMHAMN95006GÖTEBORG C87071TRELLEBORG C80520MALMÖ LINDEBORG CENTRUM33437VYSTEBORGSVÄGEN 27 BÅSTAD435959SKARHULT SKATTEBORG FLYINGE238027LINDEBORGSGATAN 1 MALMÖ306369LILJEBORGSGATAN 1 TRELLEBORG235750SÖVDEBORGSGATAN 3 MALMÖ37006BIBLIOTEK TRELLEBORG193244BÖSTE BED & BREAKFAST TRELLEBORG193083HOTELL & PENSIONAT MAGLARP TRELLEBORG67151HOTELL HORIZONT TRELLEBORG48053KATTEBÄCKSSKOLAN TRELLEBORG"

let name = "FRISKVÅRDSENHET LIMHAMN"

func isDigit(_ c: Character) -> Bool {
    let unicodeScalars = String(c).unicodeScalars
    let unicodeScalar = unicodeScalars[unicodeScalars.startIndex]
    return CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(unicodeScalar)
}

if let range = input.range(of: name) {
    var index = input.index(before: range.lowerBound)

    while (index != input.startIndex && isDigit(input[index])) {
        index = input.index(before: index)
    }

    if (index != input.startIndex) {
        index = input.index(after: index)
    }

    print(input.substring(with: index..<input.index(before: range.lowerBound)))


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, your approach returns the code missing the first digit (4 digits if it was a 5-digit code, 5 if it was a 6-digit one)